# Android RingtoneManager "Title" and "Artist" info

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I set ringtone, it works correctly but ".MediaColumns.TITLE" and ".Media.ARTIST" don't work. I have set ringtone then I check.  Shows file name instead of "Title Name".

My Code;

```
public boolean setRingtone(int p, String s) {

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
    String filename = s+'.mp3';

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Title Name");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Ringtones");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());

    getContentResolver().delete(uri,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri,values);
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(SingleListItem.this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);

    String desc= "Ringtone has been set";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), desc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;

}
```

I have these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert looks correct... I have used almost identical code and it works.  Where does it show file name instead of "Title Name"?  In the phone settings or when you query again for the media entry in the database?  If it is when you query, make sure you are indexing into the proper column to get the string:

```
Uri ringtoneUri = ...however you are getting the URI...
String[] retCol = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE };
Cursor cur =   context.getContentResolver().query(ringtoneUri,retCol,null,null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE ));
    //Do something with name...
}
cur.close();
```

Comment: It shows in phone settings. I have checked in phone settings, it shows "filename" (namely, String s) instead of "values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Title Name");"